# What is the function of human Trypsin Inhibitor if trypsin is secreted in the inactive form of Trypsinogen?

Tags: human-biology, enzymes, human-physiology, digestive-system

I was reading about pancreatic digestive enzymes in a Textbook of Medical Physiology and I came across Trypsin Inhibitor. The text stated that:

> *It is important that the proteolytic enzymes of the pancreatic juice not become activated until after they have been secreted into the
> intestine because the trypsin and the other enzymes would digest the
> pancreas itself....  ....substance called trypsin inhibitor. This
> substance is formed in the cytoplasm of the glandular cells, and it
> prevents activation of trypsin both inside the secretory cells and in
> the acini and ducts of the pancreas.*

It also states that:

> When first synthesized in the pancreatic cells, the proteolytic
> digestive enzymes are in the inactive forms *trypsinogen*,
> chymotrypsinogen, and procarboxypolypeptidase, which are all inactive
> enzymatically. They become activated only after they are secreted into
> the intestinal tract.

My question is, why is Trypsin Inhibitor secreted if trypsin is already secreted as trypsinogen which can only be activated in the intestine?

Comment: I think this is a pertinent question, which deserves more attention. My own brief survey suggests that there is no simple answer. If nobody else answers I'll summarize what I can find when I have a moment.

Comment: @David As you say, it is not an easy answer. It's a matter of time.

Comment: @Chris I’m not blaming anyone. Just trying to draw attention and let the poster know that he might have to wait for a proper answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted with an answer at: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24834/why-is-trypsin-inhibitor-present-if-trypsin-is-already-secreted-in-form-of-tryps Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @BryanKrause — Thanks for noticing that, and saving me spending my time duplicating someone else’s work. Which is one good reason why cross-posting is anti-social.